# Grunt: Generate array of files in a folder

Tags: gruntjs

I'm working on a preloader function, and was wondering if `Grunt` could help me generate an `array` of the image URLS in a defined folder?

I would like to generate a JSON-file with the `array` of the files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't know about "URLs", but the [Grunt file API](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) allows you to expand a glob pattern into an array of file names, would that work?

```
var fileList = grunt.file.expand(
    { /* any options you need */},
    ["/src/images/*.png"] // file glob pattern
);
```

Comment: THanks. I have edited the question. I defined what I would use it for. Thanks.